# Sort Filter updates both block and page within single view

Tags: views

I had this working, but can't seem to figure out what I did. I have a view that contains a block and a page. I have embedded the block into the page and exposed sort criteria on both. I want to be able to sort either the block by clicking on the title and have it update the block table and the page or click the sort criteria drop down on the page to update the block table and the page. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The default setting is that it will apply to all displays- make sure you choose only the specific one you want.